# Criteria for representability of a functor from schemes to sets

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ct.category-theory

I have read in several texts that in order to show that a given functor from the category of schemes (over, say an algebraically closed field $k$) to $\mathsf{Set}$ is representable, it suffices to check that it is representable in the subcategory of affine schemes. How is this the case? I have not been able to find a proof of this fact, and it may be rather trivial, but I do not see the connection.

Comment: Check out EGA I.2.3.6 (new edition).

Comment: @Fred do you mean https://github.com/ryankeleti/ega ?

Comment: @David: No, that's (unfortunately) a translation of the first edition. I mean the 1971 Springer edition (MR3075000).

Comment: @Fred sadly, I had a look for this on SpringerLink, and it doesn't seem to be there! Other 1971 volumes of the Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften are available digitally (modulo paywalls)...

Comment: @David: Yes, it is indeed a bit hard to find (but far superior to the first edition!). If you wish, you may send me an email.

Comment: An electronic version of EGA I (2nd edition) can be found here: http://gen.lib.rus.ec/book/index.php?md5=08FF5993E8A88EEDAEFB940FF9DD9987

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The statement

> to show that a given functor [$F\colon \mathsf{Sch}^{\mathit{op}}\to\mathsf{Set}$] is representable, it suffices
>   to check that it is representable in the subcategory of affine schemes

isn't exactly true: for example, if $X$ is a scheme that's not affine, $\mathrm{Hom}(-, X)$ is representable in
$\mathsf{Sch}$, but not in the subcategory $\mathsf{AffSch}$ of affine schemes.

What is true, though, is that any representable functor is determined (up to natural isomorphism) by its
restriction to $\mathsf{AffSch}$. This is because, for any schemes $X$ and $Y$, $U\mapsto \mathrm{Hom}(U,X)$ (for
$U\subset Y$ open) is a sheaf on $Y$ in the Zariski topology, and every scheme $Y$ admits an affine open cover.
Hence we can determine $\mathrm{Hom}(Y, X)$ from the collection of $\mathrm{Hom}(U, X)$ as $U$ ranges over the
affine open subschemes of $Y$.

This leads to the statement that you might have seen: if you're defining a scheme by first defining a functor
$F\colon\mathsf{Sch}^{\mathit{op}}\to\mathsf{Set}$, then checking that $F$ is representable, you actually only need
to define $F$ on affine schemes. This is particularly useful for defining group schemes, e.g. defining
$\mathrm{GL}_n$ by checking that the functor $\mathrm{Spec} R\mapsto \mathrm{GL}_n(R)$ is representable.

(Note: I might have misinterpreted you when you wrote “it suffices to check that it is representable in the
subcategory of affine schemes” – if you didn't mean the incorrect statement, then sorry about that!)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am still a bit confounded. How is it that it suffices to define our functor $F:Sch^{op}\rightarrow Set$ on affine schemes? How do we know it has an extension to all schemes, then?

Comment: We don't know that _a priori_. But if $F$ is represented by some scheme $X$, then $F$ is determined by its restriction to affines. Let $Y$ be another scheme and $\mathfrak U$ be an affine open cover of $Y$; then the set $F(Y) = \mathrm{Hom}(Y, X)$ is the subset of $\prod_{U\in\mathfrak U}\mathrm{Hom}(U, X)$ consisting of tuples of maps which agree on all pairwise intersections.

Comment: @JoakimFærgeman Maybe this helps: the restriction functor induces an equivalences of categories between Zariski sheaves on $\mathrm{Sch}$ and Zariski sheaves on $\mathrm{AffSch}$, so to give one is the same thing as to give the other.

Comment: Maybe I was unclear in my question, or maybe you have already answered it, and I dont understand. In any case, I am dealing with the following situation: I have a contravariant functor from Schemes to Sets. I know that it is representable when restricted to affine schemes. Can I conclude that it is also representable on Schemes?

Comment: @Joakim: What precisely do you mean by "it is representable when restricted to affine schemes"?

Comment: I mean, when it is seen as a contravariant functor on the affine schemes, there exists an affine scheme X such that X represents the restricted functor

Comment: I think (without checking all the details) that it follows from the result in EGA I mentioned above that the answer to your question is yes if your functor is a Zariski sheaf on the category of all schemes. I have no idea about the general case.

Comment: I agree that if the functor is a Zariski Sheaf, the answer would be yes. I wonder if it is even true in general.